# Removing almost all directories and files in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Quick question : I want to delete all but 1 file and 1 directory from the directory I am currently in. How do I do this?

The case scenario :

I have a directory which has three directories a b c and three files 1.php 2.php 3.php. I want to remove directories a,b and files 1.php and 2.php ONLY! I am having a hard time trying to do this.

The solution should scale up, i.e. I don't want to have to list all the files I do want to delete, only the ones that should stay.

What do I do?

Comment: to delete a folder use `rm -rf folder` question is a bit unclear about  how the structure looks like, perhaps post the output of `ls -R`

Comment: This question would be better on superuser.com or askubuntu.com, as it is not about programming. (I voted for migration.)  If you actually want to write a program which does this, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Fredrik : Thank you. The question is how do I delete all but one directory and one file from a directory i am currently in?

Comment: @Paulo : Oops! I was debating whether I post it here or on superuser. Then got carried away by similar questions asked here and also because stackoverflow allowed me to tag the post with Linux and Ubuntu tags :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in bash

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -r !(3.php|c)
```

Demo

```
$ mkdir -p x/a x/b x/c
$ cd x
$ touch {1,2,3}.php
$ ls -F
1.php  2.php  3.php  a/  b/  c/
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo rm -r !(3.php|c)
rm -r 1.php 2.php a b
```

See [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) in the bash manual.

Comment: Beat me to it. Setting `shopt -s extglob` makes it easy. Wonder why it isn't on by default as it is in Kornshell?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
cd <directory>
rm -r a b [12].php
```

Comment: Thanks Arafinwe. How does that solution scale up when I have 20 directories and 30 files, and I want to delete all but 1 directory. Its going to be tough to mention every single dir name and file name that way, and do the rm operation. Assume that I will need to recursively delete the directories.

Comment: @sniper `rm -r [^c] [^3].php`

Comment: @sniper Huh, it works for me. What happens if you type `echo [^c] [^3].php`?

Answer (score 0):

For deleting all but one file in a general case, it gets more complicated.

Here is a solution in bash (or other shells, I did not check on which ones it works):

```
function deleteAllBut() {
  local pattern="^($1)"
  for p in "${@:2}"
  do
    pattern="$pattern|($p)"
  done
  pattern=$pattern\$
  for f in *
  do
    [[ $f ~= $pattern ]] || echo $f
  done
}
```

Then you can call

```
deleteAllBut c 3.php
```

to list all local files but these two ones. (This will not delete hidden files, e.g. ones whose names start with a `.`.)

How does it work? It first builds a regular expression from the command line arguments (which beforehand were expanded by the shell), then iterates through all files in the current directory and echoes all ones that do not match the pattern.

Change the `echo $f` to `rm -r $f` to actually delete those files and directories.

---

*The following is the original answer for the original question.*

```
cd <your directory>
rmdir a b
rm 1.php 2.php
```

This assumes your directories are empty. If they are not (and you want to remove the contents, too), use

```
rm -r a b
```

instead of the second line above. (`-r` stands for *recursive*.)

Of course, you then can combine the last two lines:

```
rm -r a b 1.php 2.php
```

or, if you want to be tricky:

```
rm -r a b [12].php
```

or

```
rm -r a b {1,2}.php
```

Comment: Hi Paulo. I wanted to retain directory c and file 3.php :)

Comment: Thanks Paulo. But I dont see that solution scaling up when I have multiple directories and multiple files. Please check my comment on Arafinwe's reply. :)

Comment: You should have mentioned that you want to delete all but one in the question.

Comment: Promptly Changed the question Paulo. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: I changed the answer to actually do some programming.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1860/discussion-between-sniper-and-palo-ebermann)